# Can we use group by and Order by in subquery

Tags: sql

I have actually some doubts. I am summing up into the one question.

Can we use Group by in the sub query.
Can we use order by in sub query.
How to use use order by and group by outside the view?

````
select x.[Date], '113' + x.[Store Code], x.BranchName, x.Total_Transaction, x.[Total_Sales_(RM)],
y.Total_Online_Transaction, y.[Total_Online_Sales_(RM)]
from (select cast (S.txdate as date) [Date], '113' + b.storeid as 'Store Code', b.BranchName, count(s.paymentamount) as 'Total_Transaction', sum(s.paymentamount) as 'Total_Sales_(RM)'
from fnb_txsales S) as x, 
(select cast (O.txdate as date) [Date], '113' + B.storeid as 'Store Code', B.BranchName, count(O.paymentamount) as 'Total_Online_Transaction', sum(O.paymentamount) as 'Total_Online_Sales_(RM)'
from fnb_TxOnlineSales O ) as y
group by TxDate,x.StoreId,x.BranchName
order by x.[Date], x.BranchName```

Please answer with the proper reason. It will be really helpful for me.

Thanks in advance.
````

Answer (score 1):

`GROUP BY` in subqueries is ok (and quite useful) in pretty much any RDBMS.

`ORDER BY` in subqueries doesn't make sense, since the order of the values is no longer guaranteed once the result reaches the outer query. Some RDBMS's (MySQL for example) will allow it, but there is no "SQL standard" on how it *should* work when it's allowed.

Vouching for the performance of functions vs. procedures for all databases is not really possible, however there is no inherent reason for one have better or worse performance than the other.